# Playing Pathfinder ACG with all adventure deck cards in early scenarios

Tags: pathfinder-adventure

My fiance and I just finished playing the Pathfinder ACG through all of the adventure decks and are thinking about getting started again with all new characters from the beginning.

The question we were debating about was whether or not to keep all of the cards from the later adventure decks together or to remove the cards that come after the scenario we're currently playing.  I feel like the game was relatively easy the first time through and it might add some challenge to have a random powerful bane appear in an early scenario.

Is there a particular rule to this or is it just up to the players to decide what they're up for?

Answer (score 1):

There is no official rule or FAQ per se. On page 19 of the rule book it gives some guidance on what to do after you have completed all the adventures.

I have read on other forums that some do go ahead, adding cards from other adventure decks, but that this will make the game more difficult.

Comment: Welcome to B&CG StackExchange! Is it possible to link to some of the forums you reference so that the OP can take a look at other discussions about the level of difficulty?